# Convert php curl to GAE urlfetch for iTunes InApp verifyReceipt

Tags: php, google-app-engine, app-store-connect, libcurl, urlfetch

Can someone help to convert this PHP Curl to UrlFetch ? This is used for Apple iTunes verifyReceipt

```
if (getiTunesProductionLevel($app_id)=="sandbox" || $sandbox_override == TRUE) {
    $endpoint = 'https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt';
}
else {
    $endpoint = 'https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt';
}

$postData = json_encode(array(
    'receipt-data' => $receipt,
    'password' => $sharedSecret));

$ch = curl_init($endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$errno = curl_errno($ch);
$errmsg = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

this is as good as I can get. But not good enough.

```
logMessage(LogType::Info,"XXX URLFetch 0");
    $postData = json_encode(array(
    'receipt-data' => $receipt,
    'password' => $sharedSecret));
$post_data = json_decode($postData);
logMessage(LogType::Info,"XXX URLFetch 1");
$data = http_build_query($post_data);
logMessage(LogType::Info,"XXX URLFetch 2");

$context = [
  'http' => [
    'method' => 'post',
    'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
    'content' => $data
  ]
];

logMessage(LogType::Info,"XXX URLFetch 3");
$context = stream_context_create($context);
logMessage(LogType::Info,"XXX URLFetch 4");
$result = file_get_contents($endpoint, false, $context);
logMessage(LogType::Info,"XXX result:" . $result);
$response = $result;
$errno = 0;
logMessage(LogType::Info,"XXX response:");
```

It is able to post but returns this response
    XXX result:{"status":21002}

Comment: What's the response status 21002 mean from the server?

Comment: here is something similar but its using curl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964728/status-21002-while-verifying-transaction-receipt

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html 21002
The data in the receipt-data property was malformed or missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you json_decode $post_data in your urlfetch code but not in curl?

Comment: thats not the answer. decode is used because it was already encoded. just for reference is that i'ved also tried directly creating the postdata array just like this $post_data = array(
    'receipt-data' => $receipt,
    'password' => $sharedSecret); And feed it directly into $data = http_build_query($post_data); . Same status. Not the solution. I need more troubleshooting technique, how can I dump the request ? I want to see how GAE construct the post.

Comment: Sorry, didn't make my answer clear. Based on https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1 you're expected to "Submit this JSON object as the payload of an HTTP POST request". In other words, $data = json_encode(array('receipt-data' => ....));

Comment: spot on! tested it and confirm working. Thanks a whole lot... you definitely really came from Mars!

Answer (score 0):

I had an error like this, it turned out 'POST' had to be in uppercase when running locally. 
On .appspot it worked with lowercase 'post' but not locally on my PC.

Comment: nope this is not it. I changed it to POST, still the same on appspot.

Comment: any idea how to set these in urlfetch ? CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER ?